# How to represent long division using KaTeX?

Tags: katex

I checked the official KaTeX docs and there seems to be no support for long division. Is there another way I can represent long division using KaTeX?

Comment: Do you mean long division in the sense of a fraction (or ratio)?

Answer (score 0):

In case you are looking for something in the sense of a fraction/ratio, you could use the `\dfrac{...}{...}` command.
For example:

```
$\dfrac{This\ is\ a\ very\ looooooooong\ statement}{This\ is\ an\ even\ loooooooooooooooonger\ statement}$
```

Resulting in:
[image]

Note that I am using `\`  (backslash + space) to create a standard spacing.

For other more complex types of fractions, please refer to the official [documentation](https://katex.org/docs/supported.html#fractions-and-binomials).